# Do I need to include partition name in the query to get the actual benefits of partitioning?

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have restructured one of my data tables (DeviceLogs) with range partition by month using date (`LogDate`) field. Following is a minimal version of my table.

```
UUID  | LogDate              | DeviceId  | Counter
------|----------------------|-----------|---------
xxxx  | 2018-08-21 15:00:00  | 23        | 45
xxxx  | 2018-08-21 15:00:00  | 24        | 23
xxxx  | 2018-08-21 15:00:00  | 25        | 120
xxxx  | 2018-08-21 16:00:00  | 23        | 55
xxxx  | 2018-08-21 16:00:00  | 24        | 30
```

Composite primary key (UUID, LogDate)

I have created the partition as follows..

```
ALTER TABLE DeviceLogs PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(LogDate)) (
    PARTITION plt201807 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2018-07-01')),
    PARTITION plt201808 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2018-08-01')),
    PARTITION plt201809 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2018-09-01')),
    PARTITION plt201810 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2018-10-01'))
)
```

I have a few sets of queries against the above table from which I will generate my database reports and graphs. I can put some example of query patterns I am using.

```
// Hourly (Last 25 hours)
SELECT DeviceId, sum(Counter) FROM DeviceLogs 
  WHERE LogDate BETWEEN '2018-08-21 15:00:00' AND '2018-08-20 14:00:00'
  GROUP BY HOUR(LogDate)
```

.

```
// Daily (Last 30 days)
SELECT DeviceId, sum(Counter) FROM DeviceLogs 
  WHERE LogDate BETWEEN '2018-08-21 15:00:00' AND '2018-07-21 15:00:00'
  GROUP BY DAY(LogDate)
```

.

```
// Monthly (Last 12 months)
SELECT DeviceId, sum(Counter) FROM DeviceLogs 
  WHERE LogDate BETWEEN '2018-08-21 15:00:00' AND '2017-08-21 15:00:00'
  GROUP BY MONTH(LogDate)
```

My Question is, first, will I get any real benefit by creating the monthly partition for the above kind of queries? second, do I need to include the partition name in the above queries to get the actual benefits of partitioning?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify a partition name. The optimizer should look at the condition and [prune the appropriate partitions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-pruning.html) for you.